# Spring Jpa Reository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I prepared the HQL query and stored in string variable.
I am using Spring JPA Repositories to deal with database.

I want to execute this HQL query using spring reprository. But I could able to find the way how to invoke this without @Query annotation.

How to run the HQL queries in Spring JPA without @Query annotation?

Comment: If your query is simple, then you can use Spring's named query methods without using any HQL. Or use session object to execute different HQL queries. But reason, why you don't want to use @Query?

Comment: How can I get session object form Repository. Here I am preparing HQL query dynamically inside the method. So I can't use @Query.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that you can try.

- Use [`@NamedQuery`](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/named). Check out [this](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-named-queries/).
- Write a [custom repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour) and then use criteria builder to interact with the database.

Comment: @dharisi - Any help?